# How to search 1 million strings in document in java?

Tags: java, search, lucene, indexing

I have a document containing 1 million lines,which needs to searched against a file that has around 8000 lines. I initially tried lucene, but the time taken to search so many search quires takes time.  Is it possible to perform such search operations??? I need to find strings that are similar to the search string in the plain text document containing 8000 lines. The possible approaches i tried with lucene:

1. index the 8000 line document and pass the 1 million search queries.
2. Index the document containing the search queries and pass the 8000 line document as search quires. I am not sure even this is an right idea.
3. A possible one: That i never tried . Index both documents and compare them for similarity. Can this even been done?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term "Lakh".  I'm seeing reference to it being used for 100,000.  Is that correct?  As in 10 lakh = 1,000,000?

Comment: Yes 10 Lkh = 1,000,000 .

Comment: What does 8000 line document contain? Are these just some keywords or some long sentences/phrases? Please post some sample contents from both documents.

Comment: They mainly contain sentences and each line is a single sentence.

Comment: what is a "match"? Entire sentence or any tokens inside these sentences?

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure Lucene will prove the best tool for this task.  That is indeed a lot of querying to do.  If you are looking for exact matches, one possibility might be generating a [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) from one of the documents (the smaller woudl probably be best), and search for matches using `HashSet.contains`

Comment: Match includes both complete and partial match. Though complete match is quite not common in this data. Yes querying this much lucene doesn't seam to be best option.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what your search criteria exactly are.

1. Lucene may be the best option if you want fuzzy results and you're ok with the time it takes.  (Other good solutions may not be much faster.) It sounds like you want to **index each line as a separate document**. Were you doing this before?

   Running 7,500 short queries against a Lucene db containing all of Wikipedia takes me 10-20 minutes on an 8-core server. So it's not instantaneous. But it might be good enough.
2. If lines in the files correspond exactly, there's an even simpler solution:

   ```
   grep -f million_lines.txt 8000_lines.txt
   ```

   I don't know how that compares performance-wise to using the 8,000 line file as the pattern set and the million line file as the input file. Anyone care to comment?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Since the content to be indexed is small,i build inverted index from it and used a simple queries string with ngrams which reduced the time and resources it used.